# SQLite StDev function call through C#

Tags: c#, sqlite, stdev

I need to calculate `StDev` in my application. Its a Windows 8.1 application with SQLite DB backend.`StDev(Column)` is the function available and it returns the StDev value when i run the query directly through Visual Studio SQLite toolbox window. But, when i try to run the same through c# code, it returns the error "`no such function: StDev`". But I am able to use `Avg, Min ,Max` functions through the code.

MyQuery :

```
SELECT Avg(Column1) AS AvgOfColumn1,Sqrt(Column1), StDev(Column1) AS 
StDevOfColumn1, Min(Column1) AS MinOfColumn1, Max(Column1) AS MaxOfColumn1  
FROM table1  GROUP BY Column2 HAVING Column2 = 154
```

C# Code:

```
SQLiteConnection connection = SQLHelper.GetConnection();
{
SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(connection);
command.CommandText = sqlMessagesQuery;
command.ExecuteQuery<table1Model>();}
```

With this above code, I can retrieve Min,max,Avg,Sqrt but not StDev which runs when i run the query directly through SQLite toolbox.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Neither `Sqrt` nor `StDev` are [built-in functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html).

Comment: But  both works and returns expected result when i run the query directly in Visual Studio SQLite toolbox.